# Retrieving items using SQL matching parameters from two lists

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to iterate through two lists in python 2.7 of matching parameters to  recover items from a database that match both. I am a novice, and I don't understand why this keep giving me the above error as I am feeding the cursor two tuples.

```
for iter in xrange (len(vc)):
    for i in sc:
        print i, vc[iter]
        cur.execute('SELECT Origional_line FROM BabsDB_Samples WHERE sample_id = ? AND visit_id = ?', ( i, vc[iter] ))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Yields:

> (1320,) (9,)
>
> sqlite3.InerfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Any reason you're not using `for v in vc:`?

Comment: Yeah could do now that you point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of `print`, it looks like the elements of `vc` and `sc` are tuples containing the IDs, not just the IDs by themselves. If you can't change how the lists are created, you need to index them when you use them in the queries.

```
cur.execute('SELECT Origional_line FROM BabsDB_Samples WHERE sample_id = ? AND visit_id = ?', ( i[0], vc[iter][0] ))
```